# Is there another way to set the DataGrid column alignment?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, alignment

Is there any direct way to set the DataGrid column content alignment other than the use of styles or templated columns?! there must be a direct way for that, its a natrual requirement!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, no. The smallest amount of XAML would be to create left, centre and right styles & templates, and then each time you create a column, set the CellStyle.